# i want to direct insert data in mysql by awk shell

Tags: shell, awk

How to directly data insert in mysql..
Hear is code

```
    awk '
    BEGIN {
    FS=";";
    }
    {
     if(NR>1)
     {
      Max =  $1
      Min  = $2
     Com  = $3
      if(Max>Com)
       {
        NMax = Max
        if(Max>Com && NMaxMin)
      {   
        NMin = Min
        if(Min1)                
      printf "%9.2f;%9.2f;%9.2f;%9.2f;%9.2f;\n", $1,$2,$3,NMax,NMin
    }' data.txt
```

#mysql -uroot -proot wcdata and table name-data_com

Thanks in advance....

Comment: note that you are missing closing braces `}`

Comment: what is `Min1` and `NMaxMin`?

Comment: If you want to insert data using command `mysql` one possibility is to call it from within `awk` with the `system()` function in awk..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one suggestion: Instead of the `printf` statement you can try:

```
istr="INSERT INTO data_com"
cstr="(Column001, Column002, Column003, Column004, Column005)"
cmd="echo "istr" "cstr" VALUES ("
cmd=sprintf("%s'%.2f','%.2f','%.2f','%.2f','%.2f'\)", cmd,a1[i],a2[i],a3[i],a,b)
cmd= cmd " | mysql -uroot -proot wcdata"
system(cmd)
```

Comment: It's *safer* to print things first, pipe to `| head` to see if it looks good, and if yes then pipe to the real command, in this `| mysql`

Comment: @janos Yes I agree... I just thought I should leave something to the OP to decide upon..

Comment: sorry but it is not work. error.. warning: escape sequence `\)' treated as plain `)'
sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected    i changed (" '%s','%.2f'...

Comment: @user3020916 Can you give some more information about the error?

Comment: @user3020916 Can you email me the awk script you are using? My email address is `hakon.hagland@uni.no`. Then I will have a look at it.